# 3 Tables Inner Join

Tags: stored-procedures

I have 3 tables: tblUser, tblRole, tblPage.

Below are the data in the tables:

**tblUser**

userID: 1 *(Primary Key)*
userName: Bob
roleID: 1 *(Foreign Key)*

**tblRole**

roleID: 1 *(Primary Key)*
roleName: Admin
pageID: 1 *(Foreign Key)*

**tblPage**

pageID: 1  *(Primary Key)*
pageName: AdminPage
pageURL: https://AdminPage...

I would like to know the stored procedure for a scenario where...
When I enter the name "Bob", I should get the pageURL "https://AdminPage..."

Thank You.

Comment: 1) Why SP? One simple query... 2) It is possible a lot of pages matched one name. What page must be reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question did not specify a particular RDBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, etc.), but here is a solution using SQL Server

```
--demo setup
drop table if exists #tblUser
create table #tblUser
(
userID int
,userName varchar(30)
,roleID int
)
drop table if exists #tblRole
create table #tblRole
(
roleID int
,roleName varchar(30)
,pageID int
)
drop table if exists #tblPage
create table #tblPage 
(
pageID int
,pageName varchar(30)
,pageURL varchar(100)
)

insert into #tblUser(userID, userName, roleID) values(1,'Bob',1)
insert into #tblRole(roleID, roleName, pageID) values(1,'Admin',1)
insert into #tblPage(pageID, pageName, pageURL) values(1,'AdminPage',' https://AdminPage')
go
----------------
--create the stored procedure
USE [Test]
GO
drop PROCEDURE if exists [dbo].[GetPageUrl] ;
go
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPageUrl] @UserName varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT p.pageURL
FROM #tblUser u
JOIN #tblRole r
    ON r.roleID = u.roleID
JOIN #tblPage p
    ON p.pageID = r.pageID
where u.userName = @UserName
END
go
--Test the stored procedure
exec dbo.GetPageUrl @userName = 'Bob'
```

---

```
| pageURL |             |
|---------|-------------|
| https   | //AdminPage |
```

Comment: Add one more role and page for that user... what's the result?

Comment: This is working ! Thanks :)